# PHP file upload not working. Getting error:

Tags: php, file, upload

To start things off, I've looked at a few similar problems on here but still can't resolve my issue here.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="filename" multiple="multiple" data-classIcon="icon-plus" data-buttonText="Upload Your File">
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']; 
$temp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']; 
if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){ 
        $location = 'uploads/'; 
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'uploaded';
        }
    } 
} else {
    echo 'error: not uploaded';
}
```

JS:

```
$('#cc-submit').on('click', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "balanced/example.php",
                data: $('#creditcardpost').serialize(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);                
                }

            });
        });
```

Error:

Undefined index: filename in /public_html/script.php on line xx (the two lines that collect the $_FILES variables.

"error: not uploaded"

Comment: It seems $_FILES doesn't contain a key for 'filename'. Did you add `enctype=multipart/form-data` to your form tag?

Comment: I just added it, and the issue persists.  :(

Comment: Can you post your form tag? Can you also `print_r($_FILES)` and see what comes out? There is another thing you should change to your code btw. `isset()` checks the existence of a variable, $name always exists in your case, whether it's empty or not. Use `isset($_FILES['filename'])` instead.

Comment: Duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: I just changed to isset($_FILES), then at the end used print_r($_FILES) and it returns an empty array: Array(

Comment: @IAteYourKitten, `isset($_FILES)` will also always be true since it's a global variable. However, see jeroen's comment above, that's your problem.

Comment: I'm looking at that.  It appears to be a very similar issue.  I will check that and see if I can fix the issue.  Thanks you guys.  I'm always surprised with how quickly you can get help here.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used print_r on $_FILES and found my files were coming through as "file-0".  I'm not doing multi file uploads, so this works for me.  And here is the solution.  PHP:

```
$name = $_FILES['file-0']['name'];  
$temp_name = $_FILES['file-0']['tmp_name'];  
        $location = '../uploads/';      
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){

        }

print_r($name);
```

And the JS that sends it needed to be worked a bit:

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});


$.ajax({
    url: 'balanced/upload.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#creditcardpost').append('<input type="hidden" value="' + data + '" name="filename" />');
    }
});
```

I've got it working.  Thanks for helping out guys.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

Comment: This outputs the same error.  This is not the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is true, he needs to use tmp_name if he wants to move the file to a different location. `name` contains the original file name.

Comment: @IAteYourKitten Check if your form use `enctype=multipart/form-data`.

Comment: +1 I don't know why this is downvoted, `$_FILES['filename']` is an array so that is not going to work when the OP tries to move the file.

Comment: I'm submitting form via jquery as well.  If that helps anyone get an idea of what's happening.  Site is: http://certitrans.com/checkout.php

Comment: @IAteYourKitten That's kind-of essential information, you should add that - and the javascript - to your post.

Comment: Ok, so $_FILES['filename']['name']; is now the first variable and it's still happening, though.  It;s still giving the error of undefined index.

Comment: @jeroen, that's correct. But that's another problem. OP should change that the first line to `$name = $_FILES['filename']['name']`

Comment: @Chris Ummm, which comment are you commenting on?

Comment: @jeroen, Your first one.

Comment: @Chris That's my point, so this answer is correct. Apart from the file not being uploaded because of ajax...

Comment: @IAteYourKitten Plus `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` in your ajax.

Comment: I did all that.  It was an issue separate from this answer.  It was with how jquery was sending the form to php, but also that I wasn't picking up the correct file in my php script.